# Running a bash script from another bash script with different permissions

Tags: bash, user-permissions

I have a bash script **archive.sh** which belongs to **User1** and has the permissions as **755**. Also there are two other scripts **archive1.sh** and **archive2.sh** in the same directory, belonging to the same user (**User1**) but with permissions **744**. The scripts **archive1.sh** and **archive2.sh** are called from inside the script **archive.sh**.

Now this script **archive.sh** is executed from another user **User2** in the same group as **User1**. Since **archive.sh** has 755 permissions, it can be executed without any problem. But inside that script there are calls to **archive1.sh** and **archive2.sh** which have 744 permissions. So if I call **archive.sh** from User2, then will it execute the two scripts inside it?

When I tried it, the child scripts are running correctly but I am not sure how

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: I have tried it and the scripts are executing. But I am not sure why as they donot have the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how the two "children" are called.

`./child.sh` will fail because you don't have the right permissions.

`/bin/sh child.sh` would work because you only need read access.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention it before. The script is called as ./child.sh but it is still ececuting.

Comment: Is it "setuid" or something? Did a quick test and "./" didn't work. Which OS?

Comment: Its Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga). Its not setuid. It has just some find and mv commands